# JSON.NET - Make attributes to check for empty string property values

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

With an attribute `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` annotating my model I am able to check, that the property value is not null.

For strings I would like to check for empty values as well. Is there a way to check if string property value is empty while using attributes in Json.NET? Or is there any other way?

This JSON should cause a problem

```
{
  "Property1": "",
   ... 
}
```

Comment: Looks like you'll have to use JSON Schema to validate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a JSON schema you can define minimum lengths for specific properties, among other things. This is reasonably simple using the additional [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) package, after slight modifications to the deserialization code to specify the schema to be used for validation. However, the Json.NET Schema library is not MIT licensed and uses restrictive/commercial licensing unlike Json.NET itself. There may be other implementations, though.

In a similar case I ended up (ab)using a `JsonConverter` to do validation instead. This is somewhat hacky as it's not *really* a converter, but the convenient thing is that it works purely by applying a Json.NET attribute to the model without any other code changes.

```
public class NonEmptyStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String)
            throw CreateException($"Expected string value, but found {reader.TokenType}.", reader);

        var value = (string)reader.Value;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw CreateException("Non-empty string required.", reader);

        return value;
    }

    private static Exception CreateException(string message, JsonReader reader)
    {
        var info = (IJsonLineInfo)reader;
        return new JsonSerializationException(
            $"{message} Path '{reader.Path}', line {info.LineNumber}, position {info.LinePosition}.",
            reader.Path, info.LineNumber, info.LinePosition, null);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
[JsonConverter(typeof(NonEmptyStringConverter))]
public string Property1 { get; set; }
```

The `Required.Always` should still be applied to handle cases where the property is missing completely, in which case the converter won't be called by Json.NET.

Comment: Just checking if anything changed since 3/2019? no built in attribute?